# google chrome and jquery ui: draggable object is moving away from mouse cursor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, draggable

This problem occurrs only in Google Chrome:

Here is a simple fiddle with draggable div: http://jsfiddle.net/8kPXf/

```
<div id="drag"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#drag").draggable();
});
```

When you drag it let's say 3 times, the **draggable div seems to move away from the cursor**.

There is another fiddle where this effect does not occurr: http://jsfiddle.net/uBPs8/

```
<div id='container'>
     <h3 class='title' id='titlebar'>My Title</h3>
</div>

$("#container").draggable({
        containment: 'window',
        scroll: false,
        handle: '#titlebar'
    });
```

The difference is that the problematic fiddle uses jQuery 1.7.2 and not 1.4, because when I changed jquery to 1.7.2 in the "good" fiddle, the problem occurred.

Is there a workaround to this problem in Google Chrome that would still allow to use jQuery 1.7.2 ?

Comment: I am only getting weird behavior in your first example when I drag your item off the page. I noticed in your second example there is a option set for `containment:'window'`, and when I added that to your first example, I couldn't break it in the same way I did the first example. Is that the problem? If not, can you be more specific on what happens when you "drag it 3 times"?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ran this fiddle in Firefox and it was OK. So it seems that it occurrs only in Google Chrome. I updated the question . Adding `containment='window'` did not change the behavior.

Comment: I don't get any weird behaviour at all. Which Chrome version are you using?

Comment: Version 26.0.1410.64 m. I don't know what the "m" means, I am using it on PC Win 7 x64.

Comment: here is a screencast with this behavior: [http://screencast.com/t/OulThm9l](http://screencast.com/t/OulThm9l) When I first click and drag it's ok. Next click+drag the div moves initially a bit to the right and down. Next click even more. And the last click+drag the div moves away completely .

Comment: Ok I definitely do not have that problem on Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m Win 8 x64

Comment: I disabled all Chrome extensions and I still have this issue.

Comment: I am using the same version of Chrome as you and I'm also on Win 7 x64 and I can't reproduce the issue. How bizarre!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the issue, using Chrome for Mac. Give this little diddy a try though, it's much more lightweight: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/